# Excel Fuzzy Lookup clearing search

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Fuzzy Lookup to reconcile camp names from two data sets. How am I able to "clear" a previous Fuzzy Lookup search? The only way I am able to re-populate the lookup parameters is to save a brand new workbook.

[column name mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suDAq.png)

Comment: Are you trying to extract `ID & Name` from `Grantee Table` if similar ID is in another Table,,, or what is the use of second Table if getting data from only one table!!

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are two tables and I must have posted the wrong picture. So sorry about that. I discovered that if I toggled the tables in the table parameter area I could "refresh" the fuzzy lookup. Thanks so much for chiming in to help me.

Comment: Glad to help you @Felice ,, you may post what u have discovered to solve the issue as an answer, ,keep asking ☺